# How to bind Kendo stacked bar chart through Model

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am trying to bind a stacked kendo Bar chart Through MVC model ,but getting an error "cannot convert lambda expression to type 'double' because it is not a delegate type".

```
@(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
    .Name("chart3")
    .Title(title => title
        .Text("Comments per day")
        .Align(ChartTextAlignment.Left)
    )
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(false)
    )
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Column(new  double[]{model => model.PerIdlingHours}
        )
        .Labels(labels => labels.Background("transparent").Visible(true));
    })
    .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
        .Categories(model => model.DataDate)
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
    )
    .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
        .Max(28)
        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
        .Visible(false)
    )
)
```

Comment: Can any body help me out

Comment: What type is 'model.PerIdlingHours'

Comment: model.PerIdlingHours is of double type.

Comment: actually i want to write it like this ,   series.Bar(new double[] { 40, 32, 34, 36, 45, 33, 34, 83, 36, 37, 44, 37, 35, 36, 46 })

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how we can create the kendo bar chart

```
@model IEnumerable< Hitec.Blackbox.Models.AllMachinesUtilization>
<div class="chart-wrapper">
@(Html.Kendo().Chart(Model)
    .Name("DailyChart")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:auto;height:200px" })
    .Title(title => title
        .Text("Daily Utilization Chart")
        .Align(ChartTextAlignment.Left)
    )
    .Legend(legend => legend
        .Visible(true)
        .Position(ChartLegendPosition.Bottom)  
    )
    .SeriesDefaults(seriesDefaults =>
        seriesDefaults.Column().Stack(ChartStackType.Stack100))
    .Series(series =>
    {
        series.Column(model => model.IdlingHours).Color("#b8b8b8");
        series.Column(model => model.StopHours).Color("#bb6e36");
        series.Column(model => model.EngineWorkingHours).Color("#f3ac32"); 
  })
            .CategoryAxis(axis => axis
                .Categories(model => model.DataDate)
                .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(false))
                .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
            )
                    .ValueAxis(axis => axis.Numeric()
                       // .Max(100)
                       .Visible(false)
                            .Line(line => line.Visible(false))
                        .MajorGridLines(lines => lines.Visible(true))
                        .Visible(false)
                    )
       .Tooltip(tooltip => tooltip
            .Visible(true)
            .Template("#= series.name #:<br/> #= value #")
                ))
            </div>
```